# How to connect mini jack output to arduino mini pro and send sound to it?

Tags: bluetooth, audio

I would like to connect arduino mini pro to mini jack output and send sound through it.

What would I need here, how can I connect the mini jack to arduino and how to send data of sounds (any library?) to that connected output?

**EDIT**

The sound source will be a music file ( streamed via bluetooth). I would like to be able to connect this output to a speaker and play (stream) music via bluetooth.

**EDIT**

Either mono or stereo will be good for me. My plan is to: stream the music via bluetooth to bluetooth module (for now I think about HC-06), send that data stream through arduino mini pro to the output mini jack.

Do I need in that case some kind of mp3/other format decoder module like [VS1003B on ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/VS1003B-MP3-Decoder-Module-Development-Board-STM32-Contains-Microphone-/121315052297?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1c3ef0cb09) ?

Comment: Low pass filter on a PWM signal?  Best to buffer it with an op-amp too.  Or just connect it through a capacitor and use tone()?

Comment: Please improve this question.  Tell us what kind of sound you want to generate, what level of quality, what the sound source is expected to be (file? tone()?), and what you ultimately want to connect the output to.

Comment: Also tell us what you have tried, and why none of the millions of tutorials available through a very quick google search are good enough for you.

Comment: @Majenko Edited.

Comment: Still not enough information.  Tell us more.  A jack is just a socket.  There's a million ways to wire it up.  The correct one depends on things like what you will plug into the jack, what quality of audio you want, whether you want stereo or mono, etc.

Comment: @Majenko I added some information, I am trying to get some information on my possibilities here - that's the reason for my question.

Comment: I think you're staring out on completely the wrong footing and anything you try will be doomed to failure. The Arduino is nowhere near powerful enough to generate high quality audio by itself. The best you could hope for is very rough low bandwidth PWM audio where you can just about make out what it is meant to be. Pointless really. You could add a DAC, like the Adafuit Wave Shield uses, but that is still low quality (22KHz, mono, 12-bit). I once made my own audio shield for the Arduino that was CD quality, but that employed an additional MCU with DSP to do the audio processing, which was...

Comment: ...10x more powerful than the Arduino, making the Arduino completely redundant. I would suggest you upgrade to a more capable platform. The Due would be better as it's a 32-bit core with built-in 12-bit DAC, but still a bit pants. Even better would be a PIC32MX470 based system and a proper I2S audio DAC.

Comment: What about this [VS1053](http://www.vlsi.fi/en/products/vs1053.html)?

Comment: You could maybe link that direct to your bluetooth module (it has a UART interface) and throw away the Arduino. Whether that UART interface will take audio data I have no clue, since it says "UART for debugging purposes" yet says "Serial control and data interfaces" - it may only refer to the SPI, so you may want the Arduino to feed the data through from UART to SPI.

Comment: I do not recommend using the HC-06 chip. First of all, it is a ***serial*** chip, thus it sends text, not audio. You might be able to convert it to character codes on the phone side, but that'd be a lot of work. Also, the baud rate might not be high enough to keep up with what you want to do.

Comment: I have found docs that say the baud rate can be set up to 1382400 [googledoc](https://docs.google.com/viewer?pid=explorer&srcid=0B2_rhDNAxM4sYm0tWXhoWGdock0&docid=a0007a9e09caf0a6cb0433e307eaaf1e%7C79d55a5676bb4dca8b6525eebbd79bbe&chan=EAAAAE8lUEUKDt8WSulKuEwSSvwiRBAXReo/1/aClWvsTHtX&a=v&rel=rar;r6;HC-06+Manual.pdf) (of few others). Any alternative for this chip(non serial one) ?

Comment: I don't really know if there's one in breakout form for such a chip. Also, for those types of chips, they would be designed to provide a direct connection to a 3.5mm jack or to a decoder chip

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin What about those type of integrated bluetooth mp3 decoder? [ebay spk d bluetooth mp3 decoder](http://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-SPK-D-Bluetooth-Audio-Receiver-Module-MP3-Decoder-And-Card-Reader-/131215153172?pt=US_USB_Bluetooth_Adapters_Dongles&hash=item1e8d085814)

Comment: Yes, that'd be better. I can't give you much advice since a.) there's no datasheet so it'd be near impossible to give you correct advice and b.) that chip is beyond the scope of Arduino SE because it doesn't use an Arduino.

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino Uno / Mini Pro is not really the right tool for the job. It has no native audio output such as a 3.5mm jack.

Having said that I am sure it can be done - but it won't be the best quality sound. I have no doubt that it can be achieved with one of the following methods:

- using the [`tone()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Tone) function.
- by using a [R-2R resistor ladder network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor_ladder) and some sort of amplification circuit.

The [Arduino Due](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-due) and the [Arduino M0](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-m0) / [M0 Pro](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-m0-pro) both have inbuilt DAC's, meaning that they can output analog signals which can be used to drive a speaker circuit.

Another option is to use a Raspberry Pi which has a native 3.5mm audio jack.

Comment: Or you can use the PWM as a poor man's DAC. That's what the [Mozzi sound synthesis library](https://sensorium.github.io/Mozzi/) does.